# Netbeans "find in files" with preview of surrounding content (like IntelliJ "Find in Path" / Eclipse "Quick Search")

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, search, netbeans, preview

Is there a quick text search in Netbeans that shows surrounding file content along with the match?

Such a search exists for Eclipse under the name "Quick search". [image: eclipse quick search screenshot]
<sub>(source: [jaxenter.de](https://jaxenter.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/quick-search.png))</sub>
.

In JetBrains IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ IDEA) the "Find in Path" operation also shows surrounding content of found matches [image: jetbrains find in path screenshot].

Is there such a thing in Netbeans?

My current workflow is to use a "find in files" in Netbeans, then I open the found results until I find a suited match with what I am looking for, and finally close the ones that I do not need. "find in files" in Netbeans is pretty good but still I find a quick search which shows surrounding content to be slightly more productive.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that preview functionality exists within NetBeans. All you can get are the lines containing the actual matches (unless there is a plugin that does what you want, but I couldn't find one). You could [raise a NetBeans Bug Report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-2082?filter=allopenissues) for this, with an _Issue Type_ of _Improvement_.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, NetBeans 11.0 shows the context of the line only as a hint or tooltip when you move the mouse over the search result line and wait for a little:

[image]